# Facet Grid not working for categorical variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I get an error when trying to create a Facet Grid with Seaborn. I have 3 categorical variables: Gender, Day of the Week, Color. I want to understand the direct correlation of all values within each category to each other.

Gender: Female, Male
Day of the Week: Mo,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun
Color:Red, Green.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="Gender",  row="Color")
g = g.map(plt.hist, "Day of the Week")
display()

Get an error:
KeyError-Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-206114> in <module>()
      2 tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
      3 
----> 4 g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="Gender",  row="Color")
      5 g = g.map(plt.hist, "Day of the week")
      6 display()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in __init__(self, data, row, col, hue, col_wrap, sharex, sharey, size, aspect, palette, row_order, col_order, hue_order, hue_kws, dropna, legend_out, despine, margin_titles, xlim, ylim, subplot_kws, gridspec_kws)
    240             row_names = []
    241         else:
--> 242             row_names = utils.categorical_order(data[row], row_order)
    243 
    244         if col is None:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2057             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2058         else:
-> 2059             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2060 
   2061     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2064         # get column
   2065         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2066             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2067 
   2068         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1384         res = cache.get(item)
   1385         if res is None:
-> 1386             values = self._data.get(item)
   1387             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1388             cache[item] = res

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3541 
   3542             if not isnull(item):
-> 3543                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3544             else:
   3545                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:
-> 2136                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2137 
   2138         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)


KeyError: 'Color'
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Can you, please, post an example of your dataframe?

Comment: This error means that the dataframe you are using has no column named `"Color"`. Of course you cannot use a non-existing column. However, even if it did have such column the code will probably fail because you cannot draw a `hist` of categrorical values. Using a `sns.countplot` would be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "Color" is the issue here. It could me misspelled . and if you are plotting two categorical varaibles try using a Bar Chart .